# How to select a range of rows from a multiple column primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to chunk through rows in MySQL 5.5 and to do this I want to select a range between two primary keys (which I can get easily). This is trivial when the primary key is only one column. However, some of the tables I need to chunk through have multiple columns in the primary key, and I haven't figured out how to make this work in a single prepared statement.

Here's an example table with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  d VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '', -- various data columns
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 2),
(1, 1, 3),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 3, 1),
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 2),
(2, 3, 1),
(2, 3, 3),
(3, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(3, 2, 1),
(3, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 3),
(3, 3, 1),
(3, 3, 3);
```

If I had two primary keys like (1, 1, 3) and (3, 2, 1), the following statement would work. a1, b1, and c1 are the values from the first primary key, and a2, b2, and c2 are the values from the second primary key:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = a1 AND b = b1 AND c >= c1
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = a1 AND b > b1
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a > a1 AND a < a2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = a2 AND b < b2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = a2 AND b = b2 AND c <= c2
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c >= 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b > 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a > 1 AND a < 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 3 AND b < 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 3 AND b = 2 AND c <= 1
```

Which gives

```
(1, 1, 3),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 3, 1),
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 2),
(2, 3, 1),
(2, 3, 3),
(3, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(3, 2, 1)
```

But the above fails when the first column is the same, e.g. (1, 2, 2) and (1, 3, 1). In this case, the 2nd and 4th SELECT select too much.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c >= 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b > 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a > 1 AND a < 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b < 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b = 3 AND c <= 1
```

Which gives

```
(1, 1, 1), -- erroneously selected from: SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b < 3
(1, 1, 2), -- erroneously selected from: SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b < 3
(1, 1, 3), -- erroneously selected from: SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b < 3
(1, 2, 1), -- erroneously selected from: SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b < 3
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 3, 1),
(1, 3, 3)  -- erroneously selected from: SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND b > 2
```

The desired output is

```
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 3, 1)
```

I would like a single statement that works with all primary key ranges, including identical values for the first and second columns. I also have tables with 4 columns in the primary key, and I'll extend the pattern in that case.

I would like a single statement per table instead of creating queries on the fly because the query will be executed up to a million times as I chunk through the tables. Some of the tables have over 100M rows.

I would rather avoid constructing multiple statements as I have hundreds to write following this pattern, and writing more would be significantly more work. I will do this if it's the only option.

I currently use parametrized queries, and generate the values programmatically from the two primary keys, taking care of required duplicate values (the a1 x3, b1 x2, a2 x3, b2 x2 in the above example) in the application layer. So passing duplicate values for parameters is simple for me to do.

My best guess at this point is duplicate the SELECTs with an additional part of the WHERE clause comparing the values of the columns of the primary keys.

Comment: Maybe its just me,but could you clarify?Where does a1,b1 come from?Edit your question with the desired results.

Comment: a1 and b1 are the values for a from the first primary key and the second primary key used to select the range. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the values of A1,B1,C1 are can you clarify and possibly post some test values that do not work in this scenario?

Comment: Updated with example values.

Comment: What's the point of using `UNION` here...? The predicate has to go on the entire block, not at the statement level.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO By `UNION`ing several `SELECT` statements, I'm able to use an index for each part and merge the results. Using the syntax in the answer below `WHERE (a,b,c) >= (1, 1, 3) AND (a,b,c) <= (3, 2, 1)` doesn't use an index, and results in a slow table scan, which will add days to the execution time. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Create a surrogate key and index each column individually.

Comment: I can't easily do that, unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this query to select a range:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE (a,b,c) >= (1, 1, 3) 
  and (a,b,c) <= (3, 2, 1)
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6cf7b/4

---

Unfortunately, MySql is not able to perform a range optimalization for the above query, see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-single-part
(chapter: 8.2.1.3.4. Range Optimization of Row Constructor Expressions)
They say that starting from verion 5.7 MySql can optimize only queries of a form:

```
WHERE ( col_1, col_2 ) IN (( 'a', 'b' ), ( 'c', 'd' ));
```

Basically the above query is equivalent to this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE  
     a = 1 and b = 1 and c >= 3 -- lowest end
     or 
     a = 3 and b = 2 and c <= 1 -- highest end
     or 
     a = 1 and b > 1
     or
     a = 3 and b < 2
     or 
     a  > 1 and a < 3
;
```

MySql might use a range access method optimalization for this form of the query, see below link
 (chapter :8.2.1.3.2. The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html

Comment: This solves the problem simply, but when I run explain, it appears to not use the index and runs a full table scan (which takes several seconds), even when I try adding a FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) clause. I was unaware of being able to do range selects like that though! Do you have any insight into using that syntax where MySQL 5.5 will use an index?

Comment: I do notice when I only `SELECT a, b, c` that explain shows MySQL using the primary key fine. As soon as I `SELECT a, b, c, d` it does a full table scan.

Comment: Yes, the query with a row constructio cannot use index, I've added additional info to my answer.

Comment: Your answer isn't exactly what I want because of the index situation, but it will work, so I'm going to accept it. I ended up going with my original idea of making a lot more unions.

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect. MySQL 5.7 **can** optimise row expression constructor form. According to [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html).